# CGridview fit with screen Resolution without Scroll

Tags: php, css, yii, cgridview

Im using Editable Grid extension of CGridview. 
MY Grid:

```
$this->widget('EditableGrid', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'template' => '{items}{pager} ',
    'id' => 'PO-grid',       
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                //'style'=>'width:1100px;'
             ),
    'columns' => array(   
            array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => '',
            'name' => 'PO_{gridNum}_{rowNum}_edit',
            'imageurl'=> Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png',
            'tag' => 'button',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(                               
                )
            ),
            array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'StentysRef',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]ref',
            'tag' => 'textField',           
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(                 
                'readonly'=>true              
                )
            ),                                               
                array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'SupplierRef',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]productref',
            'tag' => 'textField',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(                   
                'readonly'=>true
                )
                ),
                array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'Product',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]productname',
            'tag' => 'textField',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(
               // 'size' => '2'
                'readonly'=>true
                )
                ),

                array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'Qty',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]qty',
            'tag' => 'textField',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(
                'size' => '2',
                'readonly'=>true,'width'=>'10px','style'=>'width:70px;'
                )
                ),
                array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'Description',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]description',
            'tag' => 'textField',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(
               // 'size' => '5'
               'readonly'=>true
                )
                ),            
                array('class'=>'CButtonColumn','template' => '{delete}',
                                'buttons'=>array(
                                    'delete' => array(                                          
                                        'options'=>array('style'=>'margin-left:20px'),
                                        'imageUrl'=>\Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/delete.png', )
                ),
                ),                                  
    ),
));?>
```

My problem is, Gridview is fit with 1600 X 900 px screen , it  should not fit with below px. 
Anyone please help me to reolve this problem. 
I want to make this grid fit with screen 1366 px.

Comment: So why you can't reduce width of elements?

Comment: Ya,Reducing Width elements working but it looks too small in 1600px screen

Comment: Than reduce elements count. E.g. with media queries.