# Setting css for Cgridview in yii

Tags: php, css, yii, media-queries, cgridview

I'm using a Cgirdview for a table structure. And I want to adjust the size of the table for different screen resolutions. I know media queries is a solution. But I don't know how to create the css.

[The code looks almost similar from that link...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651033/cgridview-fit-with-screen-resolution-without-scroll)
In my code I've used css using html options from the extension. But I want a custom css for different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a custom(new) `CSS` file to the `CGridView` like below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/myCustomCssFile.css',
```

And in that css file, write your own codes, such as media queries and so on.